# expected primary-expression before ' ' token simple error

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
void buildList(node* &h, int auditoriumNum, string fname)
{
    ifstream fin(fname);
    int row = 0;
    if(fin)
     {
          string line;
          while(!fin.eof())
          {
              getline(fin, line);
              row++;
              for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
              {
                  if (line[i]=='#')
                  {
                      insert(node* &h, row, i++, 0, auditoriumNum);
                  }
                  else (line[i]=='*')
                  {
                      insert(node* &h, row, i++, 1, auditoriumNum);
                  }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

And I get the error at lines 14 and 18 and have no idea as to why. This function is meant to read through a file line by line and for each character, call another function to add to a linked list.

Comment: `insert(node* &h, row, i++, 1, auditoriumNum);` ---> `insert(&h, row, i++, 1, auditoriumNum);`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah yes thank you seemed to have overlooked that

Comment: Also `else(...)` -> `else if (...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert(node* &h, row, i++, 0, auditoriumNum);
```

The first parameter has faulty syntax. Should have been

```
insert(&h, row, i++, 0, auditoriumNum);
```